# Inline chunk output in Quarto in VScode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, r-markdown, quarto

In Rstudio, I can show the output of the chunk just below the chunk.

Any idea how this can be implemented in VScode? I couldn't find a way to do it.

[image]